# Can Meteor be used inside of an Ionic 2 Application?

Tags: meteor

I've been looking but haven't really found anything.

Wondering if anyone on SO knows something more.

The meteoric project only works on Ionic 1, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I found this atmosphere package for ionic2-meteor: https://atmospherejs.com/barbatus/ionic2-meteor

I was able to successfully create a Meteor app, add this package, and build the project.

I also found https://github.com/Muffasa/ionic2-meteor-starter that looks like it adds Meteor to an Ionic2 application which better addresses your question.  I have not tried it out myself however.